# Not a function Error in Protractor POM

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

I am new to Protractor and I ve been trying to do a sample project with POM . I have my  page objects and functions in spec.js and trying to access it in additionTest.js , but I get

> spec.clickGoButton is not a function

My code structure looks like below

spec.js

```
   var spec=function(){
   this.goButton=element(by.id(goButton));
   this.clickGoButton=function(){
   this.goButton.click();
    };

module.exports= spec;
```

additionTest.jp

```
   var spec = require('./spec.js');

   function add(a, b) {
    spec.clickGoButton();
   }
```

I get error as spec.clickGoButton is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `spec.js` is exporting `spec` properly - it's exporting a *class*, which is meant to be called with `new` in the consuming module. You need to create a new instantiation before using its methods:

```
const Spec = require('./spec.js');
const mySpec = new Spec();
function add(a, b) {
  mySpec.clickGoButton();
}
```

But do you *really* need a class? You could just export an object instead in `spec.js`, and then use it without instantiation:

```
const spec = {
  goButton: element(by.id(goButton)),
  clickGoButton: function(){
    this.goButton.click();
  },
};
```

Comment: Still when I export the class. and instantiate with new still I get the same error, but exporting just the object works fine. The reason I wanted to export the class was, there were several other objects which needed to be exported. I ve added the comment, how I am exporting the spec from spec.js. TIA

Comment: Either you're not instantiating it properly, or you're not calling the instantiated object when you're using `clickGoButton`